# How do you retrieve a variable?

Tags: c#

This is the code where I'm having the issue, I'm trying to retrieve a value for the number of incorrect guesses ( numbWrong ). How come I can't retrieve the number of incorrect guesses?

```
...
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess letter using lowercase only.");
    char input = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray()[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < myWord.Length; i++)
    {
        //if the user guessed right, replace the correct dash and display to the user
        if (myWord[i] == input)
        {
            count++; //update the count
            a[i] = input;  //if guess is correct, dash is replaced by what the user used as input

            //show the new dash array mixed with correct guesses
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(a[j] + " ");
            }
            else
            {
                numbWrong += 1;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You guessed it right after ");
        Console.Write(numbWrong);
        Console.Write(" incorrect guesses.");
    }
```

Error:

```
"Use of unassigned local variable 'numbWrong' "
```

Comment: What is wrong with `numbWrong`? That is "retrieving" a variable, no?

Comment: It says "Use of unassigned local variable 'numbWrong' ".

Comment: Search for the error message on SO - there are *many* duplicates, and an answer should be easy to find.

Comment: declare and initialize ur numbWrong like `int numbWrong = 0;`

Comment: Add to your question with more code: we can't see how you're declaring the variable numbWrong, specifically, if it's been initialised...

Comment: You code doesn't compile. Can you check and fix please?

Comment: Voted to close as Typo (regardless of what the message says above). Uninitialized variable(s).

Answer (score 3):

Your variable isn't initialized. Take it out of the loop and place it in your code as below. Hope that helps. edit: prescot got it first. Same answer however.

```
int numbWrong = 0; //change
for (int i = 0; i < myWord.Length; i++)
{
    //if the user guessed right, replace the correct dash and display to the user
    if (myWord[i] == input)
    {
        count++; //update the count
        a[i] = input;  //if guess is correct, dash is replaced by what the user used as input

        //show the new dash array mixed with correct guesses
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(a[j] + " ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        numbWrong += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: correction: variable isn't _initialized_, not declared. The error says that it's declared, but not initialized. A big difference !

Comment: True enough - Edited to reflect. A minor gripe but a valid one nevertheless

Comment: That fixed the issue, allowing numbWrong to show, but it shows up as "25" as the result. Any thoughts??

Comment: This seems like some sort of "hangman" game or alike? and it's likely because you're iterating over all of the words in your 'myWord' array. A better way would be using something like @Aydin Adn's post. the Contains() returns true/false if the input is contained within myWords which saves the first for loop. We are also left assuming that by what you've said you have 26 words in your myWords array, 1 of which is the correct option. As such - increasing numbWrong on each incorrect response and getting '25' returned to you should be expected behaviour. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that may be it

Comment: On reflection @Aydin Adn's post is probably exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you define `numbWrong`? Before your `for` loop, you should declare `numbWrong`:

```
int numbWrong = 0;
```

Comment: correction: you should _initialize_ `numbWrong`, not declared. The error says that it's declared, but not initialized. A big difference !

Answer (score 1):

This should help you, you weren't initializing your variable, once initialised your method of counting the incorrect guess was wrong, this is because you were counting it for every iteration of each character, when it should have been counted once for each iteration over a word.

```
void Main()
{
    int numbWrong = 0;
    int maxAttempts = 10;

    string myWord = "example";
    string dashed = "-------";
    char[] dashedArray = dashed.ToCharArray();      

    for (int attempts = 0; attempts < maxAttempts; attempts++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess letter using lowercase only.\n");
        char input = Console.ReadLine()[0];

        if (!myWord.Contains(input))
        {
            numbWrong++;
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < myWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myWord[i] == input)
            {
                dashedArray[i] = input; 
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine (new string(dashedArray));
        if(!dashedArray.Contains('-'))break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine ("Wrong: {0}", numbWrong);
}
```

Comment: Way to teach by example +1

Comment: That showed me how to remedy the issue, but where exactly did the single-iteration count take place versus what I had? Is  if (!myWord.Contains(input))
        {
            numbWrong++;
            continue;
        } all that is necessary?

Comment: Essentially what we're doing is seeing if the word contains any characters that match what was submitted by the user __before__ we begin to iterate through each character of the word. You had this logic in the character iteration, so 1 error would show up as 7 errors, because there is 7 characters in the word `example` even though there was a single attempt.  Is it necessary you ask... Yes, for it to work as expected it is necessary, what part of it are you having trouble with I can try to explain it a little more for you to understand